# How can we work out the timezones in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am making a Social networking website and really this one got up on my nerves.

How to handle the time zones in a PHP and MySQL based Social networking site so that any user accessing from any country. I will explain it briefly

I have a table called posts and I execute a mysql query to place the content, User's Name, User's pic and the time it was posted ago.

For example, if someone in India is a friend with someone in london. The indian guy posts on the profile of london guy and it pops up a notification saying that the indian guy has posted on his profile 5 and half hours ago. How can I correct that?

Please give a helpful reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any kind of PHP framework that can help you manage your users' timezones/locales?  You should store your data in mysql in UTC, and then convert it to the local timezone when displaying to the user.  How you will know the local timezone of the user depends on how your application is set up.

Comment: PHP has built-in support for timezones in DateTime and DateTimeZone classes. Show somethings you've tried and we'll help

Answer (score 0):

use `timezone-offset-get` to correct based on server time.

```
/**    Returns the offset from the origin timezone to the remote timezone, in seconds.
*    @param $remote_tz;
*    @param $origin_tz; If null the servers current timezone is used as the origin.
*    @return int;
*/
function get_timezone_offset($remote_tz, $origin_tz = null)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php